Unable to get issuer certificate
I got this error when I tried to build my Angular project. I tried to run my application from my local machine while connected to my web API from IIS server and it is working.
I already tried the solution below but did not work.
npm config set strict-ssl false
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

This is my error

Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
